# How do I select a specific element from a set with similar XPath paths?

Tags: java, xpath

There are 2 drop-down lists. Each has a similar meaning, for example, "Jorge". Lists in different modules. When I need to fill in, for example, a list that is lower in the tree, then the first match is taken along the XPath path, on an undisclosed list.

Not lists, but values in drop-down lists!

There are 2 drop-down lists. Each has a similar meaning, for example, "Jorge". Lists in different modules. When I need to fill in, for example, a list that is lower in the tree, then the first match is taken along the XPath path, on an undisclosed list.

Not lists, but values in drop-down lists!

I wanted to implement it in Java this way:

Example:

```java
if (findElement(By.xpath("(//example//example)")).isDisplayed()) {
  findElement(By.xpath("(//example//example)")).click();
}
```

But in this case, the element is not displayed.

How to implement a search of all values similar to the XPath path in order to get the one that is displayed?

I tried to do something like this: (//example//example)1 (//example//example)[2] (//example//example)[3]

In my case, we have that 1 - the element does not exist [2] - exists, but is not displayed (isDisplayed = false) [3] - exists, is displayed (isDisplayed = true)

iterating through the values in the loop for [n] cannot be implemented, because, for example, the value 1 is not.

Described as difficult as possible :D. Excuse me.

If someone understands my nonsense, please help me. How to implement my requirement?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zrfw.png)

UPD:

The problem was solved (for me) by substituting the first value into the expression ()"{1}" immediately.

Now I'm interested in why I get an exception after the first iteration:
Method threw 'org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException' exception.

Code:

```
int number = 1;
        String option = "(//ul[contains(@style, 'display: block')]//li//span[contains(text(),'" + valueField + "') or strong[contains(text(),'" + valueField.toUpperCase() + "')]])";
        findElement(By.xpath(option+"["+number+"]"));
        String[] words = valueField.split(" ");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            builder.append(words[i]);
            setFieldByLabel(nameModule, nameLabel, builder.toString());
            fastWaitLoading();
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                if (findElement(By.xpath(option+"["+number+"]")).isDisplayed()) {
                        new Actions(browser.getWebDriver())
                                .moveToElement(findElement(option))
                                .click()
                                .build()
                                .perform();    
                   break;
                }
                number++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am trying to fully understand your question, and I don't. What I would recommend for a situation like this is, iterate through all elements by creating a list with: findElements(By.xpath ... )

This way you will get a list of webelements and you can iterate through them. Then apply a foreach, assert if element is displayed (it exists as it has been found with findElements) and you should be able to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, everything is in a prominent place)

Missed it

```js
new actions(browser.getWebDriver()) .moveToElement(findElement(**option**)) .click() .build() .perform(); break;
```

Here

```js
new actions(browser.getWebDriver()) 
    .moveToElement(findElement(**option + "[" + number+"]"**)) 
    .click() 
    .build() 
    .perform(); 
break;
```